# Do I need to make Pagination for Android Cursor

Tags: android

I Have a `Query` that gonna load about `5k` (i.e 5000) records in a `Cursor` , The question is Do i need to make pagination for the `Cursor`  ? or it will stream the `5k` records ?

Comment: does it load the whole 5k records in memory ?

Comment: i know from java world that ResultSet stream's the records do this apply to cursor in android  ? if not ? how to do the pagination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll give you 5k records. As long as you don't do something really time-consuming with them, like network or file access, then you probably don't need to paginate.